# How to transmit Sockets between Celery tasks

Tags: python, sockets, networking, celery

My celery tasks are **creating connections** to send data over them and if the connection is not ready for writing (If it's **blocking** too much) then I want to send the connection to a queue to be used when it's ready for writing (So the task for sending data will be queued again)

**In other words**, I'm trying to **transfer** socket objects in Celery and the problem is that socket objects are **not** **serializable**.

The **question** is:
Is there a way to transmit **open connections** between Celery tasks?

(By the way, if you think that my approach is bad, you are welcome to advise me a better one)

Comment: There is no simple way to transfer a socket from one process to an other. So only a single processed celery worker could hold the sockets. Also using a queue might result in a socket waiting too long and time out. You should consider running the whole task at once and compensate the waiting time by running more worker processes / threads.

Comment: What if I'll make the worker work only with threads, and the sockets will be shared between threads. So for each worker I'll launch a task that will handle the sending of data and it will be like a reactor.. Is there a simple way to do that? Is there a way to share sockets between threads of celery tasks (and not processes)?